# SQL Server loop rows and perform a calculation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, loops, rows

i have a table which dictates the frequency of an event being triggered, in this instance it is an SMS being sent to recipient x for the current week.

The table structure is...

- [TemplateID] int, not null
- [TemplateName] varchar(100), not null
- [PrizeDraw] bit, null
- [Frequency] int, null
- [WeeklyMax] int, null
- [MessageContent] varchar(max), not null
- [IncludeOptOut] bit, not null
- [DateAdded] datetime, not null
- [Active] bit, not null

I have this set up at the moment and it works fine sending to customer 2000 once in a week (templateID 37). I now want this to be a bit more complex, where I am adding a new template (TemplateID 38) which will be sent out [Frequency] = 1500 [WeeklyMax] = 5

In other words, I want this new SMS to be sent to customer 1500, 3000, 4500, 6000, 7500

How can I loop though this table where the record has a value in the frequency field (not all do), literally I want an output that looks like:

```
Template ID | RecipientNumber
37 | 2000
38 | 1500
38 | 3000
38 | 4500
38 | 6000
38 | 7500
```

Please can anyone give me any pointers on how to do this.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: RecipientNumber  % Frequency = 0

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/